# Change DropDownMenu List item selected color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formsy-material-ui

Hello I am trying to change the selected color of a material-ui element but I cannot find any information on how to do that. I want to change this pinkish color to be blue.

[image]

edit: maybe this is the way to go but I cannot make this work:

```
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/lib/styles/getMuiTheme';

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({}, {
  menuItem: {
  selectedTextColor: 'white',
  },
});
```

Comment: what did you tried else ? add your code here

Comment: I tried all of the other conventional ways of changing this style. I maybe have found the solution but I cannot make it work:

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement the solution that I had in mind:

```
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({}, {
  palette: {
    accent1Color: 'blue',
  },
});
```

and in the render:

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
```